# How do I pass a VB variable to a JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I know nothing about Javascript/Jquery but I'm wanting some numbers to spin round like an odometer and stop on the value of a variable I have in VB. I found this JQuery and Script/CSS that does the trick but I need to change the 9999 in the code below to be the value of 'points' which I have in the VB code.
Any help appreciated.

```js
<link rel="stylesheet" href="odometer-theme-default.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="odometer.js"></script>

<script>
setTimeout(function(){
$('.odometer').html(9999);
}, 1000);
</script>

<p class="odometer">0000</p>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: And you want that value to be updated every second from the VB code, right?

Comment: I don't know what's in odometer.js, but the Javascript code shown will not cause the value to "spin", it will simply wait one second and then change the value directly to 9999.

Comment: It all works.. It's quite clever actually.. I found it here.. http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/  All I need to know is how to set the maxValue in the VB code before it tries to display it. I have done as hsh suggested below but still getting "Variable not declared">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a protected variable in your code behind:

```
Protected MaxValue As Integer
```

Give it a desirable value in page load event and use it like this inside your web form:

```
<%=MaxValue %>
```

or you can define and manipulate it in the form it self like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="odometer-theme-default.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="odometer.js"></script>

<script>
   <% Dim MaxValue as Integer = 123 %>
   setTimeout(function(){
      $('.odometer').html(<%=MaxValue %>);
   }, 1000);
</script>

<p class="odometer">0000</p>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply.. I have tried both ways but I must be missing something.. It still tells me that the variable is not defined..


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="odometer-theme-default.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="odometer.js"></script>

    Dim points as integer = 321

    <script>
   <% Dim MaxValue as Integer = points %>
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('.odometer').html(<%=MaxValue %>);
    }, 1000);
    </script>

    <p class="odometer">0000</p>

    </asp:Content>

Comment: @Eggybread, in the code above you should define point like this:`<%Dim points as integer = 321`%>, put server code insde <% %>,and if you want to print it any where in form use <%=YourVariable %>

Comment: Thanks again for your reply.. I have sorted it now using what you have said combined with a session variable. Since I'm just learning.. I keep struggling with how to use FindControl so I use session variables to get round it until I can work it out :-)